# How can I make an objects rotatable only for the player?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, rotation

the problem is that if the player touches something that rotate, the player automatically starting rotating too because the object that is rotation right now pushed the player's colliders and and player starting rotating. I want to make my player un rotatable to another objects in the game but rotatable if the player rotate by himself

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class camera : MonoBehaviour
{

    public enum RotationAxis
    {
        MouseX = 1,
        MouseY = 2
    }

    public RotationAxis axes = RotationAxis.MouseX;

    public float minimumVert = -45.0f;
    public float maximumVert = 45.0f;

    public float sensHorizontal = 10.0f;
    public float sensVertical = 10.0f;

    public float _rotationX = 0;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (axes == RotationAxis.MouseX)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensHorizontal, 0);
        }
        else if (axes == RotationAxis.MouseY)
        {
            _rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensVertical;
            _rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, minimumVert, maximumVert); //Clamps the vertical angle within the min and max limits (45 degrees)

            float rotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y;

            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_rotationX, rotationY, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you could look at the layer-based collision detection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the rotation in a field and thus making sure the only thing changing it is your script:

move it to [`LateUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html) in order for it to be the last thing called in a frame (also see [Order of Execution for Event Functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html))

```c#
float xRotation;
float yRotation;

void Start()
{
    xRotation = transform.localEulerAngles.x;
    yRotation = transform.localEulerAngles.y;
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    if (axes == RotationAxis.MouseX)
    {
        yRotation += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensHorizontal;

    }
    else if (axes == RotationAxis.MouseY)
    {
        xRotation -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensVertical;
        //Clamps the vertical angle within the min and max limits (45 degrees)
        xRotation= Mathf.Clamp(lastXRotation , minimumVert, maximumVert); 
    }

    // always overwrite with fixed values instead of using transform.rotation based ones
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);
}
```

just to be sure you could also additionally but it to `FixedUpdate` in order to also reset changes from the Physics. If there is any RigidBody in play this should be the way to go anyway but then not using the `Transform` but rather the `Rigidbody` component.

```c#
void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);
}
```

---

**Note** however: As you currently have it setup you will get unexpected rotations. Rotating around the two axis here has the problem of also rotating along the local coordinate system.

**In general you should rather have a parent object for the Y rotation and only do the X rotation on the object itself.**